# What would be the fastest method: script setup or setup function

Tags: vuejs3

In Vue3, which of the two methods would be the fastest to run:

```html
<script setup></script> <!-- 1 -->
<script>setup() return {}</script> <!-- 2 -->
```

Comment: PS: you also need an `export default {` for the #2, so let's say that you can save a few keystrokes maybe. Or use your code editor's snippet capabilities if you're a micro-management optimizer kind of person!

Comment: No, we followed your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both will probably achieve exactly the same result once sent to the compiler since the first one is sugar syntax.
No real performance gains here, just a matter of DX preference.

And **even** if there is a 0.03 ms gain, I would start by optimizing your images/fonts/3rd party analytics injected by GTM, first.